# MYSQL query select distinct month and year

Tags: sql, mysql, select, distinct

I have a table with a datetime column with multiple dates in. I want to output the month and year for every row that exists only once. e.g "`April 2017`, `April 2018`, `May 2018`, `June 2018`"

I've managed to get the below working, this displays "April May June", but it needs to display April twice as it is in different years and I also want to display their respective years.

```
<?php $results = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(date_added) AS "Month" FROM payments') or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($link)); ?>

<?php foreach($results as $result) :?>
    <?php $monthText = date("F", strtotime("2001-" . $result['Month'] . "-01")); ?>
            <?= $monthText ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've been researching for hours and not manged to find a solution that works.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can apply the `distinct` keyword to a combination of fields:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(date_added) AS "Year", MONTH(date_added) AS "Month" FROM payments
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I tried that myself but didn't know they needed to be comma separated.

Answer (score 5):

You have to group:

```
SELECT MONTH(`date_added`) AS `Month`, YEAR(`date_added`) AS `Year`
FROM `payments`
GROUP BY `Month`, `Year`
```

Answer (score 2):

With the later versions and strict rules you will not get the right response from either of the above answers as `GROUP BY` operates before the `SELECT` part of the query and hence it does not respond to aliases.

You need

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(`date_added`) AS `Month`, YEAR(`date_added`) AS `Year`
FROM payments GROUP BY MONTH('date_added`), YEAR(`date_added`)
```